# Simplest way to implement .NET events for C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, events, com

I have a .NET library, that needs to be exposed for COM interop, including some asynchronous operations. As such, I need to implement events. Implementing events from C# seems easy as:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("...")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IClass1Event))]
public class Class1: IClass1
{
    public delegate Int32 IntIntFunc(Int32 arg);
    public event IntIntFunc Event;

    public Int32 RaiseEvent(Int32 param)
    {...}
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("...")]
public interface IClass1
{
    Int32 RaiseEvent(Int32 param);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("...")]
public interface IClass1Event
{
    Int32 Event(Int32 param);
}
```

But I have trouble implementing a C++ event sink.
Various examples I've come across range from plain `IConnectionPoint::Advise` to mere "use VB", but I come across every kind of problem trying to implement them (and no, I can not use VB) - either ATL refuses to implement `AddRef` for me, or I can not grasp VTables with my mind (I am very basically versed in C frameworks, unfortunately).
I have no information on what framework is preferable, only that client is C++.

So my question is: what'd be the leanest way to expose .NET events to C++, and consequently, what'd be the simplest way to implement a test sink?

P.S.: Do I really need an events interface to be IDispatch?

Comment: You don't need to make your events interface `IDispatch` if you only use your COM objects in C++, however you do if you start using the same objects from JavaScript or other scripting languages.

Comment: There are many c++ implementations for event handlers, one I can recommend is boost.signals2 (the terminology is different, but the introduction is quite good at explaining what's what, doc there: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/signals2.html)

Answer (score 1):

C++ vtables are very easy, if you're familiar with COM. Microsoft pretty much defined them to be identical. That's to say, the MSVC++ vtable for `class IUnknown` is binary the same as the COM function table of `interface IUnknown`.

Now, you seem to stumble on `IConnectionPoint::Advise`. That's understandable. It looks like an interface that you must implement, but it isn't. It's an interface implemented by the event source. You use it to tell the source what sink to use.

To see what happens, pass a dummy `IUnknown` object to `IConnectionPoint::Advise` and put a breakpoint on your `IUnknown::QueryInterface`. You'll see the event source query for `IClass1Event`, by GUID of course. Now, when you implement that, you can return it from `IUnknown::QueryInterface`.

You don't need to implement an `IDispatch` interface. .Net can do without; it's the old Visual Basic 6 which needs it. That's because VB6 is weakly typed and needs late binding.

[More reading material.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9014/Understanding-COM-Event-Handling)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was familiar with `IConnectionPoint`s, my real problem was automated implementation of event sink object in VC++. I finally managed to do that with an **ATL** object template and a **dual interface**. As my solution is completely awful an in no way optimal, I still can not answer my question myself yet...